# Problem with sending email info via website php js and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, contacts

I don't know what's going wrong but for example when I press the send button in the contact.html
nothing happens and then I cant rewrite the form above.
I've tried the form --> contact-process.php but same results.

```
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <div class="popup_box ">
                <div class="popup_inner">
                    <h3>Make an Appointment</h3>
                    <form class="#">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <input id="datepicker" placeholder="Date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <input id="timepicker" placeholder="time">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-select wide" id="default-select" class="">
                                    <option data-display="Choose services">Choose services 1</option>
                                    <option value="1">Choose services 2</option>
                                    <option value="2">Choose services 3</option>
                                    <option value="3">Choose services 4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-select wide" id="default-select" class="">
                                    <option data-display="Choose Barbers">Choose Barbers</option>
                                    <option value="1">Zaki</option>
                                    <option value="2">Ronky</option>
                                    <option value="3">kalu</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone no">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Your email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

this is on part of the contact HTML that
when I press send button "stucks"
and I cant click on the placeholder space again.

contact.html

```
<section class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">
            

                <div class="row">
                <!-- This creates one blank line -->
                     &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="contact-title">Get in Touch</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder=" Name"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder="Enter your name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="media contact-info">
                        <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h3>somwhere, somewhere.</h3>
                            <p>streetnaem3A, PC 5555</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media contact-info">
                        <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-tablet"></i></span>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h3>+34 6894938554</h3>
                            <p>Monday-Saturday (16:00 - 20:00)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media contact-info">
                        <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h3>myemail@gmail.com</h3>
                            <p>Ask me for anything anytime!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

---

in this code Idk what should I put on link
contact-process.php

```
<?php

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
$cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

$headers = "From: $from";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$subject = "You have a message from your Bitmap Photography.";

$logo = 'img/logo.png';
$link = '#';

$body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
$body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
$body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
$body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
$body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
$body .= "</tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
$body .= "</tbody></table>";
$body .= "</body></html>";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

    echo 'done';
}else{
    echo 'mail not sent';
}
?>
```

---

why is this disabled?
$('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
and the js here

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {
    "use strict";


jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
}, "type the correct answer -_-");

// validate contactForm form
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            subject: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            number: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "come on, you have a name, don't you?",
                minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            subject: {
                required: "come on, you have a subject, don't you?",
                minlength: "your subject must consist of at least 4 characters"
            },
            number: {
                required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "no email, no message"
            },
            message: {
                required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                minlength: "thats all? really?"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"contact_process.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#success').modal('show');
                    })
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#error').modal('show');
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
    
      })(jQuery)
      })
```

one more js here

```
// -------   Mail Send ajax

 $(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#myForm'); // contact form
    var submit = $('.submit-btn'); // submit button
    var alert = $('.alert-msg'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
            url: 'mail.php', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.attr("style", "display: none !important");; // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

Comment: On your contact HTML page, your class `.container` div seems to be missing its closing div tag.

Comment: Is anything being sent? If you have chrome, you can use the developer tools, which can be opened via F12. Select Network, and then select XHR, then click on the submit button. You should be able to view if anything is being sent to PHP.

Comment: When i open XHR seems like it sending something.
(shows some green lines )

Comment: Too much code. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. Isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).